# UniToolbox2.UniTreeView Not Displaying Images - Alternatives?

Tags: ms-access, unicode, activex

I am updating an existing Microsoft Access application to use the [`UniToolbox2.UniTreeView`](https://www.iconico.com/UniToolbox2/) control because of a unicode character set requirement. This TreeView will be replacing a `MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2` control. But I am having a problem with displaying an image with each row / node. Below is the code that I have written to attempt to display the image.

Code to setup treeview...

```
Treeview1.ImageList = LocImgCtl
Treeview1.Checkboxes = True
Treeview1.Style = tvwTreelinesPlusMinusPictureText
```

(Where `LocImgCtl` is a `UniToolbox2.UniImageList` control.)

Code to assign which image within the `LocImgCtl` control gets displayed.

```
Treeview1.Image = someInteger (logically decided)
```

What am I missing here? Is there another activex solution out there that I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a decent amount of time working on this, I finally figure out how to get this to work in Access.

> **Set** Me.Treeview1.ImageList = Me.LocImgCtl.**Object**

So as far as I can tell, a UniToolbox2.UniTreeView control is a direct replacement for the standard windows treeview. I hope this helps someone!